# Headless Browser + OCR to solve captchas

Tags: node.js, python-3.x, web-crawler, puppeteer

I'm trying to solve captchas in a headless browser. Is there a way to use OCR with a headless browser or is this not possible? I'm not committed to puppeteer if there is something that will work better for headless solution.

I ran a simple puppeteer crawler that goes to amazon and takes a screenshot 4-5 times, but then a captcha came up so I'm trying to figure out how to integrate OCR in headless to solve this problem.

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to avoid captchas using random user-agents each request, like this (https://www.npmjs.com/package/random-useragent):

```
const randomUseragent = require('random-useragent');
await page.setUserAgent(randomUseragent.getRandom());
```

Comment: If I add to cart > view cart > continue to checkout > enter email > on enter password it also asks for a captcha so I'm not sure if user agent will get me all the way to checkout https://postimg.cc/wRXbDnY0 Do you have any suggestions?